# Simplify/RESTify my routes(2)!

Tags: ruby-on-rails, rest, routes

I have  ways to get my list of images, here they with the corresponding

1/ get images according to filters sent as parameters

```
images/list_filtered?order=<order>&page=<page>&per_page=<count_per_page>&user_id=<user_id>&device_id=<device_id>
```

2/get the images of the people that the user_id's user is following: news feed

```
images/news_feed?order=<order>&page=<page>&per_page=<count_per_page>&user_id=<user_id>&device_id=<device_id>
```

3/ images inside boundaries (i.e. inside a map)

```
images/inside?order=<order>&page=<page>&per_page=<count_per_page>&user_id=<user_id>&device_id=<device_id>&lat1=<lat1>&lng1=<lng1>&lat2=<lat2>&lng2=<lng2>
```

But we cannot define it like this in routes.rb if images is a resource (then list_filtered, news_feed, or inside would be considered as an ID)

So I see 2 solutions:

1/ 3 custom routes outside the images resources, breaking the REST approach for these:

```
images_list/filtered
images_list/news_feed
images_list/inside
```

2/ filtered, news_feed and inside are also get parameters, and I dispatch inside the `index` action with something like `self.send(params[:type])`

Both solutions are pretty ugly, and would like to find the right approach, any thoughts?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Assuming you want all the normal resource routes too:

```
resources :images do
  collection do
    get 'filtered'
    get 'news_feed'
    get 'inside'
  end
end
```

then `rake routes` will output:

```
 filtered_images GET    /images/filtered(.:format)  {:action=>"filtered", :controller=>"images"}
news_feed_images GET    /images/news_feed(.:format) {:action=>"news_feed", :controller=>"images"}
   inside_images GET    /images/inside(.:format)    {:action=>"inside", :controller=>"images"}
          images GET    /images(.:format)           {:action=>"index", :controller=>"images"}
                 POST   /images(.:format)           {:action=>"create", :controller=>"images"}
       new_image GET    /images/new(.:format)       {:action=>"new", :controller=>"images"}
      edit_image GET    /images/:id/edit(.:format)  {:action=>"edit", :controller=>"images"}
           image GET    /images/:id(.:format)       {:action=>"show", :controller=>"images"}
                 PUT    /images/:id(.:format)       {:action=>"update", :controller=>"images"}
                 DELETE /images/:id(.:format)       {:action=>"destroy", :controller=>"images"}
```

http://guides.rubyonrails.org/routing.html#adding-collection-routes